# Microsoft word insert index in page order

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

How do i insert the document index using 
**`MS word>>References>>Index>>Insert Index`**

When follow the above steps my index is inserted by is of title alpha sort. I want that to be of Page number ordered (ascending)
[image: Word Image]

I am using MS office 2013

Comment: Word's INDEX feature (and the { INDEX } field and { XE } fields it uses to create the index) does not have any options to do that.

Even if you modified all your XE fields to include a page number at the beginning, e.g. using a nested field like { XE "{ PAGE } the index text" }, you would probably get an alpha sequence where page 123 would be sorted before page 2, and there are other problems.

Instead of XE fields, perhaps use TC fields and a TOC field. Why not have a look at that? If that doesn't get you closer, you are likely to need to use VBA or some such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An undocumented feature of the index tools is the semicolon. You can override the sorting of the item and place it in the order as if it were the new text.

For example, if you have two index fields that read as this:
{XE "zebra;page 4"}
{XE "abbot;page 42"}

Then the index will sort it so that zebra comes before abbot. You could apply this each of your indexes, maybe append letters to your page numbers like 4a or possibly subcounters like 4.1 and 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the index tick the 'right align page numbers' checkbox.
(this creates an index with a tab between the entry and page number)
Highlight the entire index when created.
Then go to Table/Sort (might vary depending on version) and sort by Field 2, A-Z.
This should then sort the index by page number rather than content.

Answer (score 1):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2VMW.png]

After selection as `Heading 1`, `Heading 2` and so on...
You can use `Table of contents` under `References` tab as shown in image provided. This will give you index in page order. You can use Index feature in MS Word at the last page for words having important meanings to them.